# CAML query daterange not working

Tags: caml-query

I am trying to retrieve list items using date range based on date column. It implicit both 'Fromdate' and 'Todate'.My CAML query is also querying on two other conditions as well. I am using the below query but it is not retrieving the data.when I remove the date range from query data is retrieved fine. But i want date range as well in my query how would i do this. Little help would work for me.

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><And><And><Neq><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Number">0</Value></Neq><Eq><FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" /><Value Type="ModStat">0</Value></Eq><Geq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime">' + fromDate + '</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime">' + toDate + '</Value></Leq></And></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" Ascending="True" /></OrderBy></Query></View>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your caml query but i have not tested it. Try this caml query. If issue occurs please let me know.

```
<View><Query>
<Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <And>
                <Neq><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Number">0</Value></Neq>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" /><Value Type="ModStat">0</Value></Eq>
            </And>
            <Geq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime">' + fromDate + '</Value></Geq>       
        </And>
        <Leq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime">' + toDate + '</Value></Leq>
    </And>
</Where>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" Ascending="True" /></OrderBy></Query></View>
```

Comment: HI rohit i tried your caml query it is not giving the results . Everything is showing empty. Could you pleasee help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used CAML query builder to re create your query. I hope this works!!
I suspect the AND clause were not properly placed.

```
<View>
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Neq>
                <FieldRef Name="ID" />
                <Value Type="Number">0</Value>
            </Neq>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" />
                    <Value Type="ModStat">0</Value>
                </Eq>
                <And>
                    <Geq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Created" />
                        <Value Type="DateTime">' + fromDate + '</Value>
                    </Geq>
                    <Leq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Created" />
                        <Value Type="DateTime">' + toDate + '</Value>
                    </Leq>
                </And>
            </And>
        </And>
    </Where>
    <OrderBy><FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" Ascending="True" /></OrderBy>
</Query>
```

This [CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Software) is a very nice and handy tool to create complex queries. You can download and use it.

Comment: HI Asad , It is not giving the results. Showing empty.

Comment: The field ID if this is the OOB List unique ID, then I guess its type should be counter. Can you try updating that.

Comment: I updated it to counter still same no results are up.